# How do I customize the location of index.js with Sentry in React Native?

Tags: react-native, sentry

Our bundle entry point is at `src/index.tsx`, which appears not to match the Sentry default of `./index.js`.

Sentry is failing on `sentry-cli react-native-xcode` with the error `EOF while parsing a value at line 1 column 0`.

Using debug log level, I see:

```
+ ENTRY_FILE=index.js
...
Error: The resource `/Users/lukecwilliams/Projects/mobile2mr/index.js` was not found.
```

And in the actual CLI command, this is being run: `--entry-file index.js`

We need instead `--entry-file src/index.tsx`.  How can we customize this?  I can't find an answer in the docs or source code.

---

I've found [this solution](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cli/issues/81#issuecomment-309139462) (custom build script) but it's still not working.

I have a script in the project root:

`sentry-cli-xcode-build.sh`:

> `./node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh ./src/index.tsx`

And in the build command in project.pbxproj:

`shellScript = "export SENTRY_PROPERTIES=sentry.properties\nexport EXTRA_PACKAGER_ARGS=\"--sourcemap-output $DERIVED_FILE_DIR/main.jsbundle.map\"\nexport NODE_BINARY=node\n../node_modules/@sentry/cli/bin/sentry-cli react-native xcode ../sentry-cli-xcode-build.sh";`

But the result is a fairly ambiguous: `error: Permission denied (os error 13)`

Do I need to change the directory setup somehow?  I don't see a concrete example in Sentry docs or the GH answer above regarding where to put the script and how to reference it exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this build step should simply be disabled in iOS projects using Bitcode (which is the default).  So, we have no more need to run a custom build script.

We'll use Fastlane afterward to upload debug symbols.

Docs for reference:: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/#ios-specifics

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

```
export ENTRY_FILE=index.ios.js
```

in the script